# Extracting lines from a file by comparing with numeric values

Tags: shell

I have some data which is of the following form :

```
|1000|1|2|abcd
|2000|1|2|djcd
|3000|1|2|eysa
|4000|1|2|adns
|5000|1|2|absd
|6000|1|2|dsvd
|7000|1|2|bejk
|8000|1|2|qwrv
|9000|1|2|vjik
|10000|1|2|msuf
```

I need to write a shell script that should print all the rows in between (and including as the case maybe) two values.

Eg. Suppose 3500 and 8000 are taken as inputs, then the output must be

```
|4000|1|2|adns
|5000|1|2|absd
|6000|1|2|dsvd
|7000|1|2|bejk
|8000|1|2|qwrv
```

Can someone please tell the required command(s) to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk -F\| -v s="3500" -v e="8000" '$2>=s&&$2<=e' file
```

the 3500 and 8000 could be shell variables.